# How to debug OSGi services

Tags: intellij-idea, osgi, pax-exam

How do I enable and debug when there are multiple services involved and tested with the help of pax exam.

I have a set of services orchestrating and providing a functionality. Each of these services have tests that mock other services. In addition to it, there are integration tests which are done through pax exam.

But when I hook a debugger through my IDE:intelliJ, and run the test the debugger doesn't get hooked. Should I be using remote debugging here and if so should I configure it in pax exam?

Answer (score 1):

With Pax Exam's Remote or Karaf Test Containers you'll need remote debugging. Using the Native Test Container, all tests run in the same VM, so plain breakpoints should work.

The Native Container is usually preferred, unless you need full classloader isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what version of Pax Exam you were using. However, in general Pax Exam launches a separate JVM when running a test, which is why your debugger does not stop at breakpoints you define. You need to first tell Pax Exam to launch that new JVM with remote debugging turned on. And then you can let your IDE connect to that remote debugger. There is actually a FAQ on the Pax Exam site about this:

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxexam/FAQ#FAQ-WhydoestheJavadebuggernotstopatabreakpointIsetinmyPaxExamJUnittest?